# Why does the linked list head pointer reference get updated when updating the tail reference?

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I am confused about how references work in JavaScript.

The context is a problem where I have to merge two sorted linked lists. The problem is as follows:

**You are given the heads of two sorted linked lists `list1` and `list2`.
Merge the two lists in a one sorted list. The list should be made by splicing together the nodes of the first two lists.
Return the head of the merged linked list.**

Definition for singly-linked list:

```
 function ListNode(val, next) {
      this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
      this.next = (next===undefined ? null : next)
 }
```

My solution is below:

```
var mergeTwoLists = function(list1, list2) {

  if (!list1 && !list2) {
    return null
  }

  let list1Current = list1
  let list2Current = list2
  let newHead = new ListNode() // dummy head node
  let newTail = newHead

  while (list1Current && list2Current) {
    if (list1Current.val < list2Current.val) {
      newTail.next = new ListNode(list1Current.val, null)
      list1Current = list1Current.next
    } else {
      newTail.next = new ListNode(list2Current.val, null)
      list2Current = list2Current.next
    }
    newTail = newTail.next
  }

 if (list1Current) {
   newTail.next = list1Current
 } else if (list2Current) {
   newTail.next = list2Current
 }

  return newHead.next
};
```

I am confused how `newHead` is being updated when `newTail` gets updated. In the beginning, `newHead` in set to an empty `ListNode`. We are only ever updating `newTail` in the while loop. How does `newHead` have the contents of `newTail`, if we are never updating `newHead`? Shouldn't `newHead` remain the empty `ListNode` at the end?

Comment: `newTail = newHead` does not make a copy, both variables point to the same node.

Comment: Both the `newTail` and the `newHead` variable hold the *same* object.

Answer (score 0):

`newHead` gets mutated in the first iteration of the `while` loop (or after the loop if one of the lists is empty).

It may help to visualise it. Let's take as example the merge of two lists which each just have one node -- one has the value 1, and the other 2.

Just before the loop starts, we have created a dummy node (with value 0) and referred to it with `newHead` and `newTail`:

```
                                      list1Current 
                                       ↓
                                     ┌────────────┐
                                     │ val: 1     │
                                     │ next: null │
 newHead                             └────────────┘
  ↓
┌────────────┐
│ val:  0    │
│ next: null │
└────────────┘
  ↑
 newTail                             ┌────────────┐
                                     │ val: 2     │
                                     │ next: null │
                                     └────────────┘
                                       ↑
                                      list2Current
```

In the first iteration we get into the `if` block (because 1 < 2), where we create a new node and assign it to `newTail.next`:

```
                                      list1Current 
                                       ↓
                                     ┌────────────┐     
                                     │ val: 1     │
                                     │ next: null │
 newHead                             └────────────┘
  ↓
┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ val:  0    │   │ val: 1     │
│ next: ───────> │ next: null │
└────────────┘   └────────────┘
  ↑
 newTail                             ┌────────────┐
                                     │ val: 2     │
                                     │ next: null │
                                     └────────────┘
                                       ↑
                                      list2Current
```

Here already you can see that what happens to `newTail` is what happens to `newHead`, as they reference the same node.

In the same iteration of the loop, `list1Current` gets a new value (`null` in this example), and `newTail` gets a new value -- the node that was just created:

```
              list1Current == null
                                       
                                     ┌────────────┐     
                                     │ val: 1     │
                                     │ next: null │
 newHead                             └────────────┘
  ↓
┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ val:  0    │   │ val: 1     │
│ next: ───────> │ next: null │
└────────────┘   └────────────┘
                   ↑
                  newTail            ┌────────────┐
                                     │ val: 2     │
                                     │ next: null │
                                     └────────────┘
                                       ↑
                                       list2Current
```

In this simple example there are no other iterations, and after the loop, `list2Current` is still not `null`, so we execute `newTail.next = list2Current`:

```
              list1Current == null
                                       
                                     ┌────────────┐     
                                     │ val: 1     │
                                     │ next: null │
 newHead                             └────────────┘
  ↓
┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ val:  0    │   │ val: 1     │
│ next: ───────> │ next: ───────┐
└────────────┘   └────────────┘ │
                   ↑            │
                  newTail       │    ┌────────────┐
                                │    │ val: 2     │
                                └──> │ next: null │
                                     └────────────┘
                                       ↑
                                       list2Current
```

Although now `newTail` is no longer referencing the same node as `newHead`, the assignment to its `next` property does influence the chain that starts at `newHead`.

Finally, as we don't want to return a list with still the dummy node in it, we return `newHead.next`:

```
                 ┌────────────┐
                 │ val: 1     │
(returned) ────> │ next: ───────┐
                 └────────────┘ │
                                │
                                │    ┌────────────┐
                                │    │ val: 2     │
                                └──> │ next: null │
                                     └────────────┘
```

I hope this clarifies it.